# Is the constructor missing something?

Tags: java

I keep getting compilation error for name constructor, what am I missing/doing wrong here :/

//I am new to coding in general, and as I have recently learnt java, I'm trying to create a name constructor that takes in the first name and last name from a .txt file, using scanner function, which will print the names onto the terminal when code is executed, but I'm facing some compilation error:

d.java:330: error: constructor Name in class Name cannot be applied to given types;

My code:

```
class Name
{
    private String firstName, lastName;
    
    //Default Constructor
    public void Name()
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
    
    //Other Constructor
    public void Name(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    //Copy Constructor
    public Name(Name n)
    {
        this.firstName = n.firstName;
        this.lastName = n.lastName;
    }
    
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    
    public void setName(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name: " + firstName + ", " + lastName + "\n";
    }
}


public static void main (String [ ] args) throws IOException
    {
             //instance variables
         String firstName, lastName;
         Name name;

             //Construct a Scanner
             Scanner input = new Scanner (new File ("input.txt"));
                
             //Input variables from input.txt
             firstName = input.nextLine();
         lastName = input.nextLine();

             //Construct the object
             Name n1 = new Name (firstName, lastName);

             Profile p1 = new Profile (n1, d1, h1, weight, year);
         }

             Name n1 = new Name (firstName, lastName);
```

Comment: The main method should be within the class Name scope

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have an error in your constructor. The constructor methods should have a return type of "Name", not "void".

Change:

```
//Default Constructor
public void Name()
{
//Do nothing
}

//Other Constructor
public void Name(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

to:

```
//Default Constructor
public Name()
{
    //Do nothing
}

//Other Constructor
public Name(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```